# Como utilizar MySQL num formulário comum?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Estou com dificuldades para utilizar um banco de dados MySQL que tenho em um host (bluehost)
em uma aplicação C#, gostaria de visualizar as tabelas em uma aplicação porém não consigo conectar ao DB , já instalei o connector , só que aparece a seguinte mensagem

> unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Como devo proceder?

Comment: Você vai precisar dar um pouco mais de informação cara... Você já verificou a string de conexão? Tentou conectar com um gerenciador de banco de dados?

Comment: Você tem algum código da sua aplicação que possa colocar na sua pergunta?

Answer (score -1):

É um pouco vaga a pergunta, mas pela mensagem possivelmente o host na connection string está errado.

Ou mesmo a porta do banco de dados pode ser diferente da padrão (porta padrão 3306) e alguns hosts trocam essa porta ou também limitam o acesso do banco a ips específicos.